# SSL/HTTPS Redirect Loop

Tags: ssl, https

I can't seem to make certain pages secure and I think I've tried everything possible.

1. .htaccess redirect
2. iTheme Security plugin
3. Wordpress HTTPS plugin
4. Changing site url to https://

For some reason, neither of the plugins can force SSL. It just enters a redirect loop. Similarly with changing the .htaccess.

However, wooCommerce pages are secure, and I've also got pages in the root of the wordpress directory that I can access over HTTPS, as well as things like uploaded content.

Where should I start looking or how can I start debugging the redirect loop?

Wordpress is version 3.8.5 with the "BigBang 1.7.3" theme. 
List of plugins:

```
Advanced Custom Fields by Elliot Condon version 4.3.9, 
Brankic Photostream Widget by Brankic1979 version 1.3, 
Brankic Social Media Widget by Brankic1979 version 1.8, 
Brankic Twitter Widget by Brankic1979 version 2.1, 
Contact Form 7 by Takayuki Miyoshi version 4.0.1, 
Jetpack Sharing butttons shortcode by Jeremy Herve version 1.2, 
Justified Image Grid by Firsh version 1.6.2, 
Multiple Post Thumbnails by Chris Scott version 1.6.4, 
Recent Tweets by ZZZ Profits version 1.1, 
Options Framework by Devin Price version 1.8.2, 
Page Links To by Mark Jaquith version 2.9.4, 
Post Thumbnail Editor by sewpafly version 2.2.1, 
Floating Social by raggedrobins (Incsub), Ve Bailovity (Incsub) version 1.7.2, 
Stripe for WooCommerce by Stephen Zuniga version 1.35, 
Widgets on Pages by Todd Halfpenny version 0.0.12, 
WooCommerce by WooThemes version 2.2.11, 
WordPress SEO by Team Yoast version 1.7.1
```

Server is running Apache.

Thanks

Comment: with no details at all it is an impossible question to answer. please edit your question to provide the details about what is actually your setup.

Comment: What further information should I include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the "force ssl on checkout" enabled in woocommerce along with another plugin like ithemes security also forcing the ssl it could be causing your redirect loop.

Comment: What's the solution when you want to force `https` sitewide and use the WooCommerce force SSL?